# AngularJS or Javascript: Sort array(ASC & DESC) using index only

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume i have a javascript object, like so:

```
var arrObject = [
{id:'01', name:'John'},
{id:'02', name:'Joseph'},
{id:'03', name:'Tom'},
{id:'04', name:'Nick'}
];
```

I have to sort the object in DESC order by index only. To sort, should not use any key from the object.
Result:

```
var arrObject = [
{id:'04', name:'Nick'},
{id:'03', name:'Tom'},
{id:'02', name:'Joseph'},// to be remove
{id:'01', name:'John'},
];
```

Suppose I have deleted third item i.e. id = '02', and added new item object. Now, Object looks:

```
var arrObject = [
{id:'05', name:'Harrison'}, //new added item
{id:'04', name:'Nick'},
{id:'03', name:'Tom'},
{id:'01', name:'John'}
];
```

So, whenever I perform Add/Delete operation on the object I have to sort the array in DESC order by index only. ***That way I can keep the new item on top always and so on.***

**Note**: No need to put the additional key in the object for sort purpose, as items from the object can be removed or added.

I do not see any built-in method would work for this directly, if yes that would great. If not, how would you go about writing a method that does this? Any help would be appreciated !!

Solution preferred in AngularJS, but Javascript also welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - arrObject is an array of objects - this allows an index in the first place.

This issue seems to be a js only issue - simply use  `unshift()` to add new items to the start of the array

```js
var arrObject = [
{id:'05', name:'Harrison'},
{id:'04', name:'Nick'},
{id:'03', name:'Tom'},
{id:'01', name:'John'}
];

arrObject.unshift({id:'06', name:'Gavin'});

console.log(arrObject); // puts the newly added Gavin object ar ethe start of the array.
```

but if you really want to `push` an item to the end of the array then - .reverse() would seem to be what you want - ie `array.reverse()` will present the array from the end to the start

```js
var arrObject = [
{id:'01', name:'John'},
{id:'03', name:'Tom'},
{id:'04', name:'Nick'},
{id:'05', name:'Harrison'},
];

arrObject.push({id:'06', name:'Gavin'});// puts the Gavin object ar ethe end of the array.

console.log(arrObject.reverse()); // renders the array in reverse orderwith the Gavin object shown first
```

Comment: Bingo!! Perfect solution. Both ways unshift() and reverse() order. I was looking at the AngularJS side, but js is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome - glad you liked the solution - happy coding :)